# How to display a dialog box once returning null to onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I am returning nothing to window.onbeforeunload which results in the default pop-up box not displaying.

Like so:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {

    return; 
}
```

Brilliant.

Now my issue is, I want to call another function which displays a custom dialog box as such:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    dialogBox() // function that generates a custom dialog box.
    return; 
}
```

I positioned the function above the return. This displays the dialog box momentarily and continues with the refresh. How can I pause the refresh completely when the dialog box is displayed?

Thank you all for your time.

Edit: My Dialog box does not return anything.

Here's the code for that:

```
function dialogBox(){
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 500,
                buttons: {
                    "Save": function() {

                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },

                    "Close": function() {
                        window.location.href = document.referrer;
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: What does dialogBox return?

Comment: Hi Douwe, thanks for your reply. It doesn't return anything. I've added the code in for you to see.

Comment: Could you try and add a `return` at the end of the dialogBox function? right afterh the `$( "#dialog" ).dialog()` ends?

Comment: Hi Douwe. I removed the return from the onbeforeunload function and added it at the end, after the dialog function ends as requested. This results in the same behaviour.

Comment: What happens if you keep both? I think you need both of the `return`'s. If that doesn't work, try to set both to `return false`

Comment: Keeping both results in the same behaviour. Switching both to return false results in the original pop up for onbeforeunload displaying (Which I didn't want) but when I select cancel on that, it displays my dialogbox. Obviously because the refresh has been halted. I've mixed and matched, by returning false in the first one and returning nothing in the second and vice versa. Unfortunately these don't fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139487/discussion-between-user1156596-and-douwe-de-haan).